# Problem with simple lunar phase algorithm in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I work on small app in Kotlin that is supposed to tell what moon phase is now by using one of 4 algortihms (choose by user) simpple, conway and 2 trigonomtric from that website: http://ben-daglish.net/moon.shtml
All algorithms should work but I have problem with the "simple" one. The catch is: they all are written in Java, so i tried to rewritte them to Kotlin and as much as I succeded by 3 of them, the first one still give me wrong answers. 
The java algorithm goes like this:

```java
function Simple(year,month,day)
{
    var lp = 2551443; 
    var now = new Date(year,month-1,day,20,35,0);                       
    var new_moon = new Date(1970, 0, 7, 20, 35, 0);
    var phase = ((now.getTime() - new_moon.getTime())/1000) % lp;
    return Math.floor(phase /(24*3600)) + 1;
}
```

Unfortunately as far as I know I can't do such data subtraction in Kotlin so I had to do the math myself, and take care about leap years (and don't have to deal with the seconds, I could have time in days) so I come up with this code:

```kotlin
    fun Simple(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): Int
    {
        val lp = 2551443
        val new_moonYear = 1970
        //var new_moonMonth = 1
        val new_moonDay = 7
        var months = intArrayOf(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
        if(year%4==0)
        {
            months[1]=29
        }

        var time=0
        time += (year-new_moonYear)*365 //+(year-new_moonYear)/4
        if(year>1972)
        {
            time++
        }

        for(i in 0..month-2)
        {
            time+=months[i];
        }
        time+=day
        time-=new_moonDay

        var phase = (time/1000) % lp;
        phase++
        return phase;
    }
```

Anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: What is your target platform? If JVM/Android, you can use `Date` in exactly the same way, and the stdlib `kotlin.math.floor` function. The biggest difference is the `%` operator becomes `rem`.

Answer (score 1):

Note, the source code you linked is Javascript, not Java.

Java (and therefore Kotlin for JDK) does indeed have a Date, class, but most of its constructors and methods are deprecated because they don't handle localization well. You can use the more recent LocalDateTime instead.

It does not use zero-based months, so there's no need to subtract 1.

ChronoUnit is one way of counting an amount of time between two LocalDateTime objects.

On the last line, you need to use doubles for the constants. Javascript makes no distinction, but if you don't use decimal places in Kotlin or Java, it divides with integers, resulting in extreme rounding.

```
fun simple(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): Int {
    val lp = 2551443
    val now = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)
    val newMoon = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0)
    val phase = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(newMoon, now) % lp
    return floor(phase / (24.0 * 3600.0)).toInt() + 1
}
```

Handling dates manually is notoriously complicated and error prone, so I didn't bother to check what's wrong with your code.

Comment: The `Instant` class replaces `java.util.Date`, not `LocalDateTime`. The `LocalDateTime` class is entirely different, unable to represent a moment as it purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Does it matter when we're only trying to find the amount of time between two dates?

Comment: I do not know in this particular case, as I do not understand the moon phase algorithm. If generic 24-hour long days are close enough for the algorithm, then your code using `LocalDateTime` is good.

Comment: Ups... I don't know why i mistake the two... anyway I correct tags to correct one.
And this solution solve the problem. Any concept of time zone or UTC offset isn't needed as this program works just one the date, without taking exact hours into consideration.
(The moon phase algorithm is just based of amount of time beetwen some date of fullmoon in the past and current date - as simple as that. But why exact that value? But why such value is used? I'm not sure maybe it's appointed experimentically.)